# How to reach to another column field using auth()->user()->student()->registration->student_id?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am having 3 table 'user', 'student' and 'registration'. Each table is link with hasOne relationship. i Want to get the value  of student_id from class table.Is it possible to find? Actually i am new i am not getting that

//CODE
`<a href="{{route('gallary.view',['stud_id' =>auth()->user()->student()->registration->student_id])}}">`

//Error
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$registration`

Comment: I removed () from student . It's shows an error. Is it possible to access another table filed which all having relation hasone?

Answer (score 0):

If student is having had one relationship than use

```
{{route('gallary.view',['stud_id' =>auth()->user()->student->registration->student_id])}}
```

Just remove round brackets after student.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your relations properly you can do something like this.

```
@php
$user_details = User::('student.registration')->where('id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
$student_id = $user_details->student->registration->student_id;
@endphp

{{route('gallary.view',['stud_id' =>$student_id])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `()` from student relation

The correct code would be

```
<a href="{{route('gallary.view',['stud_id' =>auth()->user()->student->registration->student_id])}}"
```